# Statistical definition of temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-conductivity, heat-engine

It is written in the book(*Concept in Thermal Physics by Blundell*) that A system will appear to choose a ***macroscopic*** configuration that maximizes the number of ***microstates*** of the system. And this statement is based on the following assumption:

1. Each one of the possible microstates of a system is equally likely to occur
2. The system's internal dynamics are such that the microstates of the system are continually changing
3. *Ergodic Hyspothesis:* Given enough time, the system will explore all possible microstates and spend an equal time in each of them

I can realize that when the numbers of **microstates** for some particular **macrostate** is highest the the probability of the system to be in that particular **macrostate** is the highest. ***But it is an Probabilistic statement we cannot say the system will definitely be in that particular **macrostate** because there are other possibilities also and their probability to be occur is non-zero.*** And I understand that as the size of the system increases the *probability of the **macrostate** with highest number of **microstates*** will increase rapidly(i.e. the probability distribution will be more sharp).

***So I cannot relate the starting statement with this reasoning and where I am getting wrong!!!!***

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a probabilistic statement. But in practical scenarios the number of microstates in the most probable macrostate is so enormously greater than the number in any other macrostate that the system spends almost all of its time in the most probable macrostate, and you would to wait many times longer than the age of the universe before you observed any other macrostate.